# VBA code does not print value from sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I got the following VBA code that aims to get the value from cell 1,1 in a sheet named "risk_cat_1" and print it.

Therefore I wrote the following VBA code:

```
Sub get_prime_values()

 Sheets("risk_cat_1").Cells(1, 1).Value = value_1
 MsgBox (value_1)

End sub
```

When I run it I get an empty MsgBox however. Any thoughts what goes wrong here?

Comment: You are inverting destination and source, try `value_1 = Sheets("risk_cat_1").Cells(1, 1).Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip your assignment from

```
Sheets("risk_cat_1").Cells(1, 1).Value = value_1
```

to

```
value_1 = Sheets("risk_cat_1").Cells(1, 1).Value
```